# Flutter error:Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a code of recording Audio in flutter. The code should work perfectly without errors, whenever I try to call it from an alert dialog I end up with an error

> The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
> RenderShrinkWrappingViewport does not support returning intrinsic
> dimensions.
>
> Calculating the intrinsic dimensions would require instantiating every
> child of the viewport, which defeats the point of viewports being
> lazy.
>
> If you are merely trying to shrink-wrap the viewport in the main axis
> direction, you should be able to achieve that effect by just giving
> the viewport loose constraints, without needing to measure its
> intrinsic dimensions.

Am trying to pass an option to record audio to an alert dialog. Users to record audio from a pop up instead of a main screen. What am I doing wrong?

What i have so far

```
 Widget setupAlertDialoadContainer() {
    return ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true, //just set this property
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      //children: listItems.toList(),
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 24.0, bottom: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                this._recorderTxt,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 48.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            _isRecording
                ? LinearProgressIndicator(
                    value: 100.0 / 160.0 * (this._dbLevel ?? 1) / 100,
                    valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.green),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  )
                : Container()
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 56.0,
              height: 56.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "Record",
                onPressed: () {
                  if (!this._isRecording) {
                    return this.startRecorder();
                  }
                  this.stopRecorder();
                },
                child: this._isRecording ? Icon(Icons.stop) : Icon(Icons.mic),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        ),
        Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0, bottom: 16.0),
              child: Text(
                this._playerTxt,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 48.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: 56.0,
              height: 56.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "Start",
                onPressed: () {
                  startPlayer();
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 56.0,
              height: 56.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "Pause",
                onPressed: () {
                  pausePlayer();
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.pause),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 56.0,
              height: 56.0,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                heroTag: "Stop",
                onPressed: () {
                  stopPlayer();
                },
                child: Icon(Icons.stop),
              ),
            ),
          ],
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        ),
        Container(
            height: 56.0,
            child: Slider(
                value: slider_current_position,
                min: 0.0,
                max: max_duration,
                onChanged: (double value) async {
                  await flutterSound.seekToPlayer(value.toInt());
                },
                divisions: max_duration.toInt()))
      ],
    );
  }
```

How am passing the data to the Alert dialog

```
showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text('Record the data collection'),
                            content: setupAlertDialoadContainer(),
                          );
                        });
```

Comment: Did you try wrapping your ```ListView``` with ```Expanded```?

Comment: yes when I try that I end up with the error `The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type BoxParentData.`

Comment: Try wrapping the ```Expanded``` with a ```Row``` or ```Column```.

Comment: error `If you are merely trying to shrink-wrap the viewport in the main axis direction, you should be able to achieve that effect by just giving the viewport loose constraints, without needing to measure its intrinsic dimensions.`

Comment: Try wrapping with a ```Container``` and give it the width property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is the error is showing when alert box is opened??
if yes my suggestion is using

```
showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return AlertDialog(
                            title: Text('Record the data collection'),
                            content: Container(
                                       child:setupAlertDialoadContainer(),
                                       height:200,
                                       width:200,
                                      ),
                          );
                        });
```

change the width and height of container according to your need